# Ember + Mocha: Test can't access store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, mocha.js

I don't get my Mocha-Tests to access the Store. I threw together a really simple JSbin. I would expect the tests to be able to access the Fixtures. What am I missing?

http://jsbin.com/denomilu/9/edit?js,output

```
var expect = chai.expect;
window.App = Ember.Application.create(); 
App.injectTestHelpers();
App.setupForTesting();
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({
    simulateRemoteResponse: false
});

App.Group = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string') 
});

App.Group.FIXTURES = [
  { "id": 1, "title": "Test 1"}
];

describe('Test', function() {

    beforeEach(function(){
        App.reset();
    });

    it("finds the fixture", function () {
      Ember.run(function(){
        var title = App.__container__.lookup('store:main').find('group', 1).get('title');
        console.log(title);
        expect(title).to.equal("Test 1");
      });
    });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    mocha.run();
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it does work. Only thing is: find returns a promise. The following code works:

http://jsbin.com/denomilu/14/edit?js,output

```
it("finds the fixture", function () {
  Ember.run(function(){
    App.__container__.lookup('store:main').find('group', 1).then(function(group){
      expect(group.get('title')).to.equal("Test 1");
    });
  });
});
```